# What I am do wrong? CSS input type file and submit

Tags: html, css, file, input, submit

What I do wrong? Why two button not in one line? Why submit button has gap in top side to 1 px than file button.

I am using Google Chrome desktop. In desktop browser this is not good. In mobile Google chrome browser this is good look. Why? What I must to write in CSS to see it in other browsers good look.

http://jsfiddle.net/uybznk4u/

```
<input type="file"><input type="submit"value="SUBMIT">

*
{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
input[type=file],input[type=submit]
{
    background:#ff0;
    border:1px solid #f00;
    padding:4px;
    height:20px;
    line-height:20px;
    width:50px;

}
input[type=submit]
{
    height:30px;
    line-height:20px;
}
```

[This is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/37OnC.png)
Thanks.

Comment: If you are talking about left gap then to make them in one line you can use margin-left: 5px; for button css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set vertical-align on your second button:

```
vertical-align: top
```

Here is the updated jsfiddle :
http://jsfiddle.net/ddwpw2ej/4/

Answer (score 0):

```
input[type=file],input[type=submit]
{
    background:#ff0;
    border:1px solid #f00;
    padding:4px;
    height:20px;
    line-height:20px;
    width:50px;

}
input[type=submit]
{
    height:30px;
    line-height:20px;
    vartical-align:top;
}
```

try this....